# Compiling issues when using the Flex compiler

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I have this file that needs to be compiled using the flex compiler, but when I compile using flex file.c, I get this error and I don't quite know what it means

```
%{
int _numargs = 10;
char *_args[10];
int _argcount = 0;
%}

WORD    [a-zA-Z0-9\/\.-]+
SPECIAL [()><|&;*]

%%
    _argcount = 0; 
    _args[0] = NULL; 

{WORD}|{SPECIAL} {  
      if(_argcount < _numargs-1) {
        _args[_argcount++] = (char *)strdup(yytext);
        _args[_argcount] = NULL;
      }
    }

\n  return (int)_args;

[ \t]+

.

%%

char **getline() {
  return (char **)yylex();
}
```

When I compile using flex filename.c this is the error that I get in my code

```
lex.c:10: unrecognized '%' directive
lex.c:14: bad character: {
lex.c:14: unknown error processing section 1
lex.c:14: unknown error processing section 1
lex.c:14: bad character: }
lex.c:14: bad character: |
lex.c:14: bad character: {
lex.c:14: unknown error processing section 1
lex.c:14: bad character: }
lex.c:14: bad character: {
lex.c:19: bad character: }
lex.c:21: bad character: \
lex.c:21: unknown error processing section 1
lex.c:21: unknown error processing section 1
lex.c:21: bad character: (
lex.c:21: unknown error processing section 1
lex.c:21: bad character: )
lex.c:21: unknown error processing section 1
lex.c:21: bad character: ;
lex.c:23: bad character: [
lex.c:23: bad character: \
lex.c:23: unknown error processing section 1
lex.c:23: bad character: ]
lex.c:23: bad character: +
lex.c:25: bad character: .
```

Comment: I think the `_argcount = 0; _args[0] = NULL;` needs to go in the same section as your includes.

Comment: The `flex` program converts a `.l` (lexical analyzer) file to a `.c` file (and usually a `.h` file too).  You don't run `flex` on `.c` files — it generates them.

Comment: @DanielWalker: that part of the code is fine. Indented code before the first pattern is inserted at the top of `yylex`. Since the actions don't return until a newline is seen, that's effectively per-line loop initialisation. Casting a pointer to`int` and back is much more problematic..